# Make Banner Image AutoScroll - Android-Java

Tags: java, android, autoscroll

I have a set of banner images that can slide when user slide it and touching image will redirect to some website..
I want to add auto scroll to the banner images, but I am not too sure how to do it, can anyone help me take a look at below code?

```
public class MyAdapter extends InfinitePagerAdapter {
    BannerPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    AutoScrollViewPager viewPager;
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> bannerAry = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Home header banner
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_banner, null);
    if (homeBanner.equalsIgnoreCase("enable") && bannerAry.size() > 0){
        gridView.addHeaderView(header);
    }

    viewPager = (AutoScrollViewPager) header.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    pageIndicator = (LinePageIndicator) header.findViewById(R.id.indicator);

    display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    float scale = (float) display.getWidth() / Constants.HOME_BANNER_WIDTH;
    int newHeight = (int) Math.round(Constants.HOME_BANNER_HEIGHT * scale);
    viewPager.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
    pagerAdapter = new BannerPagerAdapter(this, bannerAry);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    pageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(mOnPageChangeListener);

class BannerPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data;


    public BannerPagerAdapter(Context act, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> newary) {
        this.data = newary;
        this.context = act;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, final int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.banner_image,
                collection, false);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        String img = data.get(position).get("image");
        Log.v("banner img", "img="+img);
        if (!img.equals("")){
            Picasso.with(FragmentMainActivity.this).load(img).into(image);
        }

        image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(data.get(position).get("url")).matches()) {
                    Intent b = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data.get(position).get("url")));
                    startActivity(b);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(FragmentMainActivity.this, getString(R.string.url_invalid), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(itemView, 0);

        return itemView;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mOnPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        enableDisableSwipeRefresh( state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE );

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }
};

private void enableDisableSwipeRefresh(boolean enabled){
    if (enabled) {
        swipeLayout.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        swipeLayout.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a TimerTask where you can schedule scroll events with some duration gap, you need to call this method after you have initialized the viewPager and pagerAdapter, here's the code:

```
private void startAutoScrolling() {

    stopAutoScrolling();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          if(activityContext!=null)
                activityContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int position = (viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1) % pagerAdapter.getCount();
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                    }
                });

        }
    };

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 3000, 3000);
}
```

here stopAutoScrolling() method it to make sure that you stop the previous running TimerTask for auto scroll which may be the case if the user returns to app after pressing the home button or taking a call.

```
    public void stopAutoScrolling() {
    Log.i(TAG, "stop auto scroll of viewpager");
    if (timer != null)
        timer.cancel();
}
```